# Does AWS Step Functions have a timeout feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Right now I have an AWS Step Function to create, run, and terminate EMR cluster jobs.  I want to add a timeout feature to stop the job and terminate the cluster in the case that a cluster gets stuck or is taking too long to run (e.g. have an input variable `"TIMEOUT_AFTER_X_HOURS": 12` passed into the state machine along with the cluster configs which will automatically stop the job and kill the cluster if it still running after 12 hours).  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: first link in google https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html

Comment: You clearly didn't understand what I was asking, your link does not help.  I want a timeout feature for the entire state machine/ emr cluster as a whole, _not_ for each individual task like in your link.  I also want the timeout length to be managed by a user input parameter, _not_ a hard-coded value in the task as in your link.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-state-machine-structure.html TimeoutSeconds (Optional) - this is how you can define timeout for whole machine, so you can generate template right before starting and thus set whole timeout

Comment: Thanks. I have this working with a hardcoded timeout value, but do you know if it is possible to have the timeout value set through an input parameter, like starting the execution with an input parameter `"timeout": 600` and setting the state machine with `"TimeoutSeconds": "$.timeout"?` I am unsure how to do this as the `"TimeoutSeconds"` only seems to accept hardcoded integer values.

Comment: Also, I will be using the state machine to run EMR clusters, do you know if it is possible to point the state machine to a specific task when the timeout occurs rather than just having the state machine halt wherever it was? I would like to have it point to a task where I can write a lambda function or something to terminate the running EMR cluster when the state machine times out, rather than the state machine just stopping and leaving the EMR cluster up and waiting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't dynamically specify the timeout for a state, but you can dynamically tell a Wait state how long it should wait. With that said, I would recommend that you use a Parallel State with two branches and a catch block. The first branch contains a Wait State and a Fail State (your timeout). The other branch contains your normal State Machine logic and a Fail State.

Whenever a branch fails inside a Parallel state, it aborts all running states in the other branches. Luckily you are able to catch these errors in the Parallel State and redirect it to another state depending on which branch failed. Heres an example of what I mean (change the values in the HardCodedInputs state to control which branch fails).

```
{
"StartAt": "HardCodedInputs",
"States": {
    "HardCodedInputs": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
            "WaitBranchInput": {
                "timeout": 5,
                "Comment": "Change the value of timeout"
            },
            "WorkerBranchInput": {
                "SecondsPath": 3,
                "Comment": "SecondsPath is used for testing purposes to simulate how long the worker will run"
            }
        },
        "Next": "Parallel"
    },
    "Parallel": {
        "Type": "Parallel",
        "End": true,
        "Catch": [{
            "ErrorEquals": ["TimeoutExpired"],
            "ResultPath": "$.ParralelStateOutput",
            "Next": "ExecuteIfTimedOut"
        }, {
            "ErrorEquals": ["WorkerSuccess"],
            "ResultPath": "$.ParralelStateOutput",
            "Next": "ExecuteIfWorkerSuccesfull"
        }],
        "Branches": [{
                "StartAt": "DynamicTimeout",
                "States": {
                    "DynamicTimeout": {
                        "Type": "Wait",
                        "InputPath": "$.WaitBranchInput",
                        "SecondsPath": "$.timeout",
                        "Next": "TimeoutExpired"
                    },
                    "TimeoutExpired": {
                        "Type": "Fail",
                        "Cause": "TimeoutExceeded.",
                        "Error": "TimeoutExpired"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "StartAt": "WorkerState",
                "States": {
                    "WorkerState": {
                        "Type": "Wait",
                      "InputPath": "$.WorkerBranchInput",
                        "SecondsPath": "$.SecondsPath",
                        "Next": "WorkerSuccessful"
                    },
                    "WorkerSuccessful": {
                        "Type": "Fail",
                        "Cause": "Throw Worker Success Exception",
                        "Error": "WorkerSuccess"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "ExecuteIfTimedOut": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "End": true
    },
    "ExecuteIfWorkerSuccesfull": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "End": true
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Used this approach successfully on a very complex state machine where I had 4 possible branches that could stop a given processing. It is unfortunate that the native parallel doesn't have a "when any" option though as that would avoid the nasty use of exceptions as control flow.

Comment: Step functions now supports addition of dynamic timeout from a state input path. See answer from @George Novack below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235388/3450425

Comment: This is a fantastic way to achieve that behaviour. I used this approach to control the max execution time of a map state. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the path to an input variable (e.g. `"$.TIMEOUT_AFTER_X_HOURS"` from the original example) to the `TimeoutSecondsPath` parameter of any Task. This will allow you to dynamically set a step timeout based on State Machine inputs or outputs of previous steps.

You can find the official Docs for the `TimeoutSecondsPath` parameter here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html

Comment: I think this is the correct and most up-to-date answer as of 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem, and I'm thinking the solution will be to create an outer state machine that manages EMR and an inner one that performs the work.

So outer would be:

- create EMR
- invoke child state machine with a `TimeoutSeconds` set on the task per your input variable
- terminate EMR

And inner would have a content of:

- perform EMR work

The inner machine therefore would return after either it completes successfully or `TimeoutSeconds` have elapsed, and in the outer machine you can detect which (using a `Catch` state to catch the `States.Timeout` error) and act accordingly.